# How to return a react component with the for in statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to iterate over a nested object with the for..in statement an return text component for each object iterated over.

```
const animals = {
  "cat": Object {
    "number": 0,
  },
  "dog": Object {
    "number": 1,
  }
{ 
      for(let item in animals) {
        for(let property in animals[item]){
          return (
            <Text>{item}</Text>
            <Text>{animals[item][property]}</Text>
          )
      }
    }
}
```

As you see above, I tried to wrap the function in curly brackets in hopes of using jsx to render the components much like one would do with .map, but I got a slew of errors, so I'm pretty sure this incorrect.

My Linter says **Expression expected** for the two for(s) and the return ().

I can console.log item, and animals[item][property] so I am confident everything outside the return () is correct.

How would I go about correctly returning the Text elements?

Comment: Honestly, this code makes no sense to me.

You have for loop about the object inside an object?

did you mean :

const animals = [object1, object2 ]

Comment: The second for loop is to access the object property. Console.log the item by itself only produced the nested object's name, and not the actual object itself. I only just learned about for in today so I might be going about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you wrote whole thing wrong.

This is my 2 cents

1st you want array not an object animals

```
const animals = [ 
  {  "name" : "cat",
    "number": 0,
  },
  { "name": "dog"
    "number": 1,
  }
]
```

than you want your component

```
const AnimalsListComponenet = () => {



return (

 <React.Fragment>
  {
   animals.map((item)=>  Object.entries(item).map((entrie)=> <Text>{entrie}</Text>
   )

  }

 <React.Fragment>

)
}
```

If you really want to iterat over object, you have to use : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: I can turn it into array, but the actual code is slightly more complicated, so I was hoping it be possible to iterate  over the object as a nested object instead of as an array. Do you think it be more effective to do as a array?

Comment: you can itterate over the object as well if you really want: 
look at this article, i will add it in my comment.:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: I will give it a try thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use react fragment, like this

```
<>
<Text>{item}</Text>
<Text>{animals[item][property]}</Text>
</>
```

Comment: Wrapping react fragments around the text element did not solve any of the issues. Thank you though.